# How to check if file is available before sending as email attachment

Tags: linux, bash, shell

If shell cannot find the attached file, can shell send the email without the attached?

How do I check the availability of the attached file, so that if it is not there, it just doesn't send the email?

Is there any flag that I can use?

```
RESULT=passed
FILE=/path/data/file.csv
LOG=/another/path/data/log.log

echo "Hello Team, 
Please check the attached log and file." |mail -s "Result-$RESULT" -a $FILE -a $LOG somebody@sample.com
```

If this `file.csv` is missing, user cannot not receive the email.

Comment: `find the attached,` [attached](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/attached) is an adjective - _something_ has to be attached. You may say "... find the attached _file_". It's not "the attached" , it's "the file" that is attached.

Comment: -a must follow an available file, is that right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A featured check for any number of potential attachments:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Array of files to check and attach if available
declare -a file_list=(
  /path/data/file.csv
  /another/path/data/log.log
)

# Create an array for mail attachment arguments
declare -a attach_args=()

declare -- attached_files='' # Display actually attached files in the mail
declare -i attached_count=0  # Number of attached files

# Iterate attachments
for file in "${file_list[@]}"; do
  # If file exist, is not empty and is readable
  if [ -s "$file" ] && [ -r "$file" ]; then
    # Add the proper attachment arguments to the array
    attach_args+=(-a "$file")
    attached_count=$((attached_count + 1))
    # Add - filename and newline
    attached_files+="- ${file}"$'\n'
  fi
done

# Check to see if there is at least 1 attachment
if [ $attached_count -gt 0 ]; then
  mail -s "Result-$attached_count" "${attach_args[@]}" somebody@example.com <<EOF

Hello Team, 
Please check these ${attached_count} attached file(s):

${attached_files}
EOF
fi
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use test -f to test if the file exists and so:

```
test -f "$FILE" && echo "Hello Team, Please check the attached log and file." |mail -s "Result-$RESULT" -a $FILE -a $LOG somebody@sample.com
```

Comment: What if file.csv does not exsit? will server send email?

Comment: If test -f fails, the rest of the line won't be executed and so no email will be sent

Comment: @RamanSailopal maybe you could rewrite your solution code in a more academic more verbose and clear form of: `if [ -f "$FILE" ]; then echo "Hello Team, Please check the attached log and file." | mail -s "Result-$RESULT" -a "$FILE" -a "$LOG" somebody@example.com; fi` with multiple lines, indenting and double quoted variable expansions.